# How do i send information about a package in a hashmap to another activity using onItemClick listener? How do i receive the information?

Tags: java, android

How do I send information about a package in a hashmap to another activity using onItemClick listener? 
Also, how do I receive the information?

Comment: What do you mean Package? :D

Comment: by package, i mean installed application package name eg. co.example.projectname

Comment: why do you need to send installed app package name? just do context.getPackageName() to get app package name :) . Sorry If I misunderstood

Answer (score -1):

HashMap use serializable interface you can send it to another activity 
by intent as:

```
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
hashMap.put("key", "value");
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyOtherActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("map", hashMap);
startActivity(intent);
```

And on receiving activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
HashMap<String, String> hashMap = (HashMap<String, String>)intent.getSerializableExtra("map");
```